# Looking for specific class when clicked

Tags: jquery, dom, element, this

I have two div containers:

```
<!-- button1 -->
<div class="voted">
    <span>name</span>
    <div class="button">Vote</div>
</div>

<!-- button2 -->
<div class="vote">
    <span>name</span>
    <div class="button">Vote</div>
</div>
```

Then when using jquery:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    // if button2 was clicked:
    var test = $(this).parent().attr("class"); // How do I obtain the other element?
    alert(test); // this should be outputted "voted"
});
```

I would like to use something like `$(this)` with some function to get the other element. How would I obtain "voted"? The reason I'm doing this is because I have a script where it will change between two buttons, so when user clicks on `button1`, I would like them to get class of `button2`, vice versa.

**EDIT**

So I have two buttons (to compare two people), initially, they're supposed to have the same class `vote`. But I have jQuery codes that when a user clicks on a button, the class changes to `voted`. Now, I would like to check so that when a user clicks on the OTHER button (to try to vote for the second person), they can't because there's already a `voted` class, or they already pressed the first button.

I know that I can just check my whole page if `voted` exists, but I have set up some check when user clicks on their initial voted person that they voted for, they can take back the vote (which will change the div class back to `vote`).

My whole premise is: not to allow user vote the other person if user already voted for someone.

Sorry for the long description.

Thanks!

Comment: What you have works: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/5JyHL/. I don't understand your question?

Comment: I don't understand this question...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rK37D/ It appears to work as you described?

Comment: Could you try to specify what it is you're trying to achieve a bit more? At the moment it's not entirely clear to me (and a lot of other people here).

Comment: @JesperKarsrud I updated my question, to hopefully give people some understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks for helping1

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan maybe my edited explanation could give u some kind of understanding on what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved what I'm trying to do

```
var voted = $(".voted").not($(this).parents(".voted")).attr("class");
```

This allows me to check if class voted exists, but it doesn't check if $(this) one that was pressed exists.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().prev().children('.button');
```

This gets you a reference to the jQuery object containing the parent's previous sibling's children with class 'button'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `siblings` method.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this).parent();
  var c1 = $this.prop('class');
  var c2 = $this.siblings('div').prop('class');
  // console.log('class 1: ' + c1 + ', class 2: ' + c2)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
        $('.button').click(function () {
            // if button2 was clicked:
            var test = $(this).parent().attr("class"); // How do I obtain the other element?
            alert(test); // this should be outputted "voted"
        });
    });
```

this code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve but all if you want to do is toggling between classes then you can use `toggleClass`

```
$('.button').click(function(){ 
   $(this).toggleClass('vote').toggleClass('voted'); 
});
```

You can always test against specific class name ('vote') to get the other class('voted'). Is there anything that prevents you from assuming hard coded class names?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out of there's a class "voted", using something like .not() or the likes, because it has the same DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to get first div's class

```
$('.button').click(function(){
      var test = $('div:first').attr("class"); // this will give first div's class
      alert(test); // this should be outputted "voted"
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q5LWN/)**